# Is there an expression that implies the same sort of idea as "what came first, the chicken or the egg?"

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Looking for a clever title for a short paper on Oscar Wilde's humor, where the reader can never quite figure out if he stands for something or nothing at all.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you’re asking but the title is a duplicate of this https://english.stackexchange.com/q/274419/191178

Comment: The chicken or egg concept isn't at all related to what you're asking about Oscar Wilde.

Comment: +1 to @nnnnnn. You maybe after something like 'The Quantum Uncertainty of Oscar Wilde's Humour and Beliefs'.

Answer (score -1):

It is a riddle. Ref:

https://me.me/i/riddles-riddles-riddle-what-came-first-a-chicken-or-egg-e0e150d058bb4a268298795a9153fc52

In a drama by Tagore, the same topic is discussed but renamed 'what is the start? Subtle or Gross'?

http://www.tagoreweb.in/Render/ShowContent.aspx?ct=Plays&bi=72EE92F5-BE50-40C7-DE6E-0F7410664DA3&ti=72EE92F5-BE50-4FE7-9E6E-0F7410664DA3

Comment: Down-vote is fine, but a comment would have been appreciated.